# maven включить ресурсы в jar

Tags: java, maven

Сделал компонент для apache-tapestry, который включает в себя java файлы и файлы js, css. При билде в jar-e файлы ресурсов отсутствуют. Сами файлы js, css лежат не в `src/main/resources`, а в пакете с java классами.
Как указать мевену, чтобы при сборке проекта он включал их в jar?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.inlandia.tap5.components</groupId>
    <artifactId>inlandia-components</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Inlandia Components Library</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Tapestry-Module-Classes>com.inlandia.tap5.services.InlandiaModule
                            </Tapestry-Module-Classes>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus.snapshots</id>
            <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>OpenQA_Release</id>
            <name>OpenQA Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://archiva.openqa.org/repository/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <tapestry-release-version>5.4-rc-1</tapestry-release-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте что-то в этом роде:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Используйте директивы `include` и `exclude`.

[Apache Maven Resources Plugin – Including and excluding files and directories](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было переместить файлы ресурсов в src/main/resources/META-INF/assets

Answer (score 0):

по умолчанию мейвен web ресурсы ищет в папке `src/main/webapp`. Кроме того вы не задумывались над тем почему папка для исходников в мейвене называется `src/main/java` ? Видимо она предназначеня только для `java` файлов (конечно туда можно положить и обычные ресурсы: конфигурационные файлы, файлы локализации но эти файлы не должны быть доступны конечному пользователю по http)